# How can I determine mySQL prepared statement result column names in PHP?

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

That is, with a prepared statement like:

```
select col1,...coln from table where col3 = ?
```

I believe I can use $mysqli->field_count to get the number of columns being returned (haven't tried).

But is there a way to link each column name to the values returned in bind_results?
I could always try to parse the column names out from the command itself, but that's not a road I want to go down.

#### Context:

I want to be able to define a PHP interface that maps class properties to column names returned from the database. So given

```
class A implements IColumnMapped{
    public $prop1, $prop2; private $map;
    public function __construct() {
        $map = array();
        $map['col1'] = & $this->prop1;
        $map['col2'] = & $this->prop2;
    }
    public function getMap() { return $this->map;}
}
```

and

```
$mysqli->prepare("select col0, col1, col2, col3 from table");
```

I can use bind_results and then do something like (pseudoish code)

```
for($resultColumns as $columnName) {
    if(isset($map[$columnName])) $map[$columnName] = $results[$columnName];
}
```

to pull out just the two columns I need (col1 and col2) and assign them to the correct properties of class A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe [mysqli_stmt::result_metadata](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.result-metadata.php) and [mysqli_result::fetch_fields](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-fields.php) could help you.

Comment: I don't believe you can get a result set out of a prepared statement can you?  The only way I know how to get results back is with bind_results() and fetch()ing each row individually.

Comment: Ah you're exactly correct!  I can use 
    $stmt->store_result()->fetch_fields()[columnIndex]->name

Thank you very much!!!

Comment: Correction:
$stmt->store_result();
$stmt->result_metadata()->fetch_fields()[columnIndex]->name;